# why I get the infinite loop in my do while statement?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

In my mind, if the input is not an integer, the loop will start, and waiting for user's next input. However, the following code looping with "value for a", and there is no chance for user to type other input.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int a;
        do{
                cout <<"Value for a: ";
                cin >>a;
        }
        while(cin.fail());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `" if the input is not an integer, the loop will start"` ... the loop will start in any case.  How do you want to break out from the loop?

Comment: see this answer: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user enters bad input, the error state of `cin` set. You cannot read anything from `cin` until you clear the error state.

You will have to:

1. Call `cin.clear()` to clear the error state, and
2. Call `cin.ingore()` to ignore rest of the line.

You'll need something along the lines of:

```
do {
   cout <<"Value for a: ";
   if ( cin >> a )
   {
      // Input was successful.
      break;
   }

   // Clear the error state of the input stream.
   cin.clear();

   // Ignore the rest of the line.
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} while (true);
```

And add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`